# Colliders not working in Unity3D 2D Project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 colliders, its a game where I have a ball, and a Labyritnh. The ball should pass through the labyrinth and collides with the labyrinth's walls.
But I have a problem, the physic aren't working that well, the collider don't work.
I have a rigidbody and a collider in both of these objects.
Also, I have a problem with choosing box or edge colliders.
Because it is a labyrinth, I need to design the colliders with some complex shapes.
I have used edges colliders and box colliders but the ball is passing through all these colliders like nothing, It seems like its not working.
Can someone help me?

Comment: uncheck isTrigger in collides.

Answer (score 1):

you need a rigid body object attached to at least one of them for the colloders to work.
make each wall individually and use rectangel colliders. add a rigidbody component, and set that rigid body to kinematic. should work then.